# Adobe Acrobat Form : Adding 5 fields and allow "-" (dash sign) in any of the fields

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-form

I want to add Five Fields (numeric) and also allow the user to enter "-" (dash sign) if no value is present instead of 0.

but when I put "-" (dash sign)  in any field it returns NaN.

Following is my script :

```
var n1 = Number(this.getField("Text1").valueAsString);
var n2 = Number(this.getField("Text2").valueAsString);
var n3 = Number(this.getField("Text3").valueAsString);
var n4 = Number(this.getField("Text4").valueAsString);
var n5 = Number(this.getField("Text5").valueAsString);

event.value = n1+n2+n3+n4+n5;
```

Comment: Acrobat allows the presentation of the data (the format) to be different from the value. If a dash were to appear in the field when the value is blank, is that acceptable or do you actually need them to enter a dash?

Comment: You apply `Number` to the field string value. "-" is not a number. Thus, what else than a NaN do you expect. Consider comparing the string value of the field with "-" first, explicitly using `0` in that case, and using `Number` of it otherwise.